# Is it meaningful for a child to create its own child (by calling fork)?

Tags: process, fork

Is it meaningful for a child to create its own child (by calling fork)?

In the following code I am unable to understand the effect of the child calling the fork:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>

#define   MAX_COUNT  200

void  ChildProcess(void);                /* child process prototype  */
void  ParentProcess(void);               /* parent process prototype */

void  main(void)
{
     pid_t  pid;

     pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0) 
          ChildProcess();
     else 
          ParentProcess();
}

void  ChildProcess(void)
{
     int   i;

  fork();   // child creates its own child process 



     for (i = 1; i <= MAX_COUNT; i++)
          printf("   This line is from child, value = %d\n", i);
     printf("   *** Child process is done ***\n");
}

void  ParentProcess(void)
{
     int   i;

     for (i = 1; i <= MAX_COUNT; i++)
          printf("This line is from parent, value = %d\n", i);
     printf("*** Parent is done ***\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any process can call `fork()`, this way a tree of processes may be formed.

That is what happens in your example, the printouts of `ChildProcess` will appear twice.